# How to pass formdata in customized button component

Tags: reactjs, react-jsonschema-forms

I have built a form using react json schema form in my react app. And my code already has a customized reusable button component. Trying to use the same button component inside the form, however I am unable to get the edited form data. Is there a way a get the latest formdata

Comment: What do you have so far? Any code examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can use form-context. which is passed to all the custom widgets.

Read more about it [here](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-customization/#the-formcontext-object)

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a state of your form data, update the state with onChange and you can access your latest form data from your component's state.